# How to make a new subset of columns from a dataframe rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm still relatively new to Python. I have data that has come in a csv like this

| ID | Postcode | Status | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | E1 2QJ | sold | June 2022 | 1000000 |
| 1 | E1 2QJ | listed | February 2022 | 900000 |
| 1 | E1 2QJ | sold | June 2018 | 850000 |
| 2 | E2 3JJ | sold | January 2022 | 1250000 |
| 2 | E2 3JJ | listed | October 2021 | 1000000 |
| 3 | E3 4IQ | listed | July 2022 | 900000 |
| 4 | E4 8RJ | sold | March 2021 | 850000 |

I would like it to look like this:

| ID | Postcode | Status | Date | Value | Status1 | Date1 | Value1 | Status2 | Date2 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | E1 2QJ | sold | Jun 2022 | 1000000 | listed | Feb 2022 | 900000 | sold | June 2018 | 850000 |
| 2 | E2 3JJ | sold | Jan 2022 | 1250000 | listed | Oct 2021 | 1000000 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | E3 4IQ | listed | Jul 2022 | 900000 | NaN | NaN | NaN | Nan | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | E4 8RJ | sold | Mar 2021 | 850000 | NaN | NaN | NaN | Nan | NaN | NaN |

Does anyone know what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [pivot tables for pandas?](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

Comment: Was thinking about the same thing too @MichaelS.

Answer (score 1):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
        "Postcode": [
            "E1 2QJ",
            "E1 2QJ",
            "E1 2QJ",
            "E2 3JJ",
            "E2 3JJ",
            "E3 4IQ",
            "E4 8RJ",
        ],
        "Status": ["sold", "listed", "sold", "sold", "listed", "listed", "sold"],
        "Date": [
            "June 2022",
            "February 2022",
            "June 2018",
            "January 2022",
            "October 2021",
            "July 2022",
            "March 2021",
        ],
        "Value": [1000000, 900000, 850000, 1250000, 1000000, 900000, 850000],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Setup
records = (
    df.groupby(["ID", "Postcode"])
    .agg(list)[["Status", "Date", "Value"]]
    .to_dict(orient="index")
)
dfs = []

# Get new intermediate dataframes (1 row, n columns)
for key, value in records.items():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [key[0]], "Postcode": [key[1]]})
    status, date, value = value.values()
    for i, (s, d, v) in enumerate(zip(status, date, value)):
        temp_df = pd.concat(
            [
                temp_df,
                pd.DataFrame({f"Status{i}": [s], f"Date{i}": [d], f"Value{i}": [v]}),
            ],
            axis=1,
        )
    dfs.append(temp_df)

# Final result
new_df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And so:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
   ID Postcode Status0         Date0   Value0 Status1          Date1     Value1 Status2      Date2    Value2
0   1   E1 2QJ    sold     June 2022  1000000  listed  February 2022   900000.0    sold  June 2018  850000.0
1   2   E2 3JJ    sold  January 2022  1250000  listed   October 2021  1000000.0     NaN        NaN       NaN
2   3   E3 4IQ  listed     July 2022   900000     NaN            NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN
3   4   E4 8RJ    sold    March 2021   850000     NaN            NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN
```